# Default hierarchical clustering method in cluster map

Tags: python, seaborn, cluster-analysis

What is the default hierarchical clustering method used in the clustermap function of seaborn? The methods are single, complete, average, weighted and centroid. Also, what is the default distance metric? Is it standard Euclidean distance? I can't find this anywhere in the documentation. I used this function on some data a few months ago, and I need to find out what clustering method was used since I didn't input any special parameters into the cluster map function. Thanks!

Comment: you can probably find out if you go into the source code for Seaborn

Answer (score 1):

From https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html :

```
seaborn.clustermap(data, pivot_kws=None, method='average', metric='euclidean', z_score=None, standard_scale=None,...
```

So by default it is average and euclidean

Comment: Thanks! It's what I thought but wanted to confirm.